# cssClass set from the code behind

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css

i tried set this `<li>`'s class from the code behind and id doesnt recognize the method cssClass:

the html:

```
<div id='settingNev' >
<ul >
  <li id="L1" class='unactive' runat="server"><a id="A1" onserverclick="show_view1" runat="server"><span>Personal</span></a></li>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

code behind:

```
protected void show_view1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
    L1.cssClass = "active";
}
```

every thing work except the line `L1.cssClass = "active";`

what is the problem? how do i fix it?

Tnx for the help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing HTML controls. `CssClass` property won't be available with these controls. You need to use the `Attribute`.

```
myList.Attributes.Add("class","active")
```